# React adding object in last of array is working fine but in begning of array its not working

Tags: reactjs

this code push end of array working fine

i tried

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
            comments: [comment, ...prevState.comments]
        })) 



this.setState(prevState => ({
            comments: [...prevState.comments, comment]
        }))
```

How I render :

```
{ this.state.comments.map(function (comment, i) { 
  return ( <CommentListItem key={i} data={comment} parentid={comment.id} postid={postid} user={user} /> ) }) 
}
```

Comment: what i want is i add to add new element in start of array and render it to component

Comment: what about using Array.concat()? `this.setState(prevState => ({comments: [comment].concat(prevState.comments)}));`

Comment: this is wokring 
this.setState(prevState => ({
            comments: [comment, ...prevState.comments]
        }))
but it not show updated value just show duplicate comment

Comment: How are you rendering the comments. Could you please show the code ?

Comment: here is how i render
` {
                            this.state.comments.map(function (comment, i) {
                                return (
                                    <CommentListItem key={i} data={comment} parentid={comment.id} postid={postid} user={user} />
                                )
                            })
                        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have come from using the array index as key. try using the id like this :

```
 <CommentListItem key={comment.id} data={comment} parentid={comment.id} postid={postid} user={user} />
```

Comment: can i pass a function in Map loop